# form submit params missing authenticity_token with Cucumber feature only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, authenticity-token

Is there a simple reason why my `form_submits` in my `Rails 3` app don't generate requests with the `authenticity_token` set in Cucumber, while they do when run as development (and production)?

The app works perfectly, except I get a redirect to the login when running my Cucumber feature tests.